# Is there way to change the Item's Font Size of ListView in Winform/C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to learn Winform in C# and I have a project similar to Cafe Shop Manager. In my project I want to add my item into ListView like Food's name? I have to try to change the font size of this item but it's causing an error in VisualStudio. Can you help me? 
Thanks anyway!!!

Comment: *but it's causing an error in VisualStudio*. What error?

Comment: include the source code where you are getting the error

Comment: What VieWmode do you use? Always tell this, whenever asking about a ListView!!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have two fonts:

```
normalfont = new Font("Consolas", 10f);
bigfont    = new Font("Consolas", 20f);
```

You can try something like this:

```
private void listView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (ListViewItem lvi in listView1.Items) lvi.Font = normalfont ;
    if (listView1.SelectedItems.Count > 0) listView1.SelectedItems[0].Font = bigfont;
}
```

Note that this will not work well when the `ListView` is in view modes `Details`, `List` or  `SmallIcon`; here you would also need to enforce a larger item height by an imagelist; not recommended. But for `LargeIcon`and `Tile` it works reasonably well..

It is OK to **cache** fonts you keep using, just be sure you don't **leak** them!

Also note that you may want to switch from the `SelectionChanged` to the `MouseClick` event to allow other types of UI interaction, like unselecting or adding up a counter. If you do you will have to do a `HitTest` on the `ListView` to find out which if any `Item` has been clicked!